# Javascript bind polyfill function with return value

Tags: javascript, bind, polyfills

I have tried making bind polyfill using this [link](https://dev.to/uddeshjain/creating-your-own-bind-polyfill-of-bind-433j)

It works fine when I use "console.log". But when I return something from the function, it returns **undefined**

Code:

```
let person1 = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
};

let showDetails = function () {
  let y = `${this.name} - ${this.age}`;
  // console.log(y) -> works fine
  return y;
};

Function.prototype.myBind = function (...args) {
  let that = this;
  params = args.slice(1);
  return function (...args1) {
    that.apply(args[0], [...params, ...args1]);
  };
};

let showDetailsBind = showDetails.myBind(person1);
console.log(showDetailsBind()); // returns -> undefined
```

Problem with this polyfill is, **default bind function** works completely fine with same procedure.

Comment: `that.apply` should be `return that.apply`

Comment: Just curious, for what purpose are you polyfilling `Function#bind`? It's been supported in browsers for a long while (about 10 years now).

Comment: @CollinD Someone asked that in the blog. The answer: "it helps us to understand how bind() works behind the scene."

Comment: I can't believe no one who commented on the blog noticed that bug.

Comment: Note that with arrow function and `call` it is easier: `= function (...args) { return (...args1) => this.call(...args, ...args1) }`